# Split a big text file into multiple smaller one on set parameter of regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, text-processing

I have a large text file looking like:

```
....
sdsdsd
..........

asdfhjgjksdfk dfkaskk sdkfk skddkf skdf sdk ssaaa akskdf sdksdfsdf ksdf sd kkkkallwow.
sdsdllla lsldlsd lsldlalllLlsdd asdd. sdlsllall asdsdlallOEFOOASllsdl lsdlla.
slldlllasdlsd.ss;sdsdasdas.

......
ddss
................

asdfhjgjksdfk ddjafjijjjj.dfsdfsdfsdfsi dfodoof ooosdfow oaosofoodf aosolflldlfl , dskdkkfkdsa asddf;akkdfkdkk . sdlsllall asdsdlallOEFOOASllsdl lsdlla.
slldlllasdlsd.ss;sdsdasdas.

.....
xxxx
.......
asdfghjkl
```

I want to split the text files into multiple small text files and save them as .txt in my system on occurences of ..... [multiple period markers] saved like

**group1_sdsdsd.txt**

```
....
sdsdsd
..........

asdfhjgjksdfk dfkaskk sdkfk skddkf skdf sdk ssaaa akskdf sdksdfsdf ksdf sd kkkkallwow.
sdsdllla lsldlsd lsldlalllLlsdd asdd. sdlsllall asdsdlallOEFOOASllsdl lsdlla.
slldlllasdlsd.ss;sdsdasdas.
```

**group1_ddss.txt**

```
ddss
................

asdfhjgjksdfk ddjafjijjjj.dfsdfsdfsdfsi dfodoof ooosdfow oaosofoodf aosolflldlfl , dskdkkfkdsa asddf;akkdfkdkk . sdlsllall asdsdlallOEFOOASllsdl lsdlla.
slldlllasdlsd.ss;sdsdasdas.
```

and

**group1_xxxx.txt**

```
.....
xxxx
.......

asdfghjkl
```

I have figured that by usinf regex of sort of following can be done

```
txt =re.sub(r'(([^\w\s])\2+)', r' ', txt).strip() #for letters more than 2 times
```

but not able to figure out completely.

The saved text files should be named as **group1_sdsdsd.txt** , **group1_ddss.txt** and **group1_xxxx.txt** [group1 being identifier for the specific big text file as I have  multiple bigger text files and need to do same on all to know which big text file i am splitting.

Comment: This is not a valid pattern `(([^\w\s])\3+)` as there are 2 capture groups in total so the backreference `\3` to capture group 3 can not be there. What is the goal to match with the pattern?

Comment: Once it hits ```..... \n
xxxx \n
.......``` I want a new text split renamed and saved as group1_xxxx.txt . So the pattern is whenever ..... \nsometext \n..... is there it will create a new text file including that line i.e  .....sometext.....  and end and save it when it got ..... \n someothertext \n....

Comment: the pattern matcher should find for a new line[\n] followed by .......... and split on the next line while saving the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the parts with multiple dots only on the same line, you can use and get the separate parts, you might use a pattern like:

```
^\.{3,}\n(\S+)\n\.{3,}(?:\n(?!\.{3,}\n\S+\n\.{3,}).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\.{3,}\n` Match 3 or more dots and a newline
- `(\S+)\n` Capture 1+ non whitespace chars in **group 1** for the filename and match a newline
- `\.{3,}` Match 3 or more dots
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\.{3,}\n\S+\n\.{3,})` Negative lookahead, assert that from the current position we are not looking at a pattern that matches the dots with a filename in between
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

Then you can use *re.finditer* to loop the matches, and use the group 1 value as part of the filename.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9yjyKB/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LmMvBK) with the separate parts.

Example code

```
import re

pattern = r"^\.{3,}\n(\S+)\n\.{3,}(?:\n(?!\.{3,}\n\S+\n\.{3,}).*)*"

s = ("....your data here")

matches = re.finditer(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE)
your_path = "/your/path/"

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    f = open(your_path + "group1_{}".format(match.group(1)), 'w')
    f.write(match.group())
    f.close()
```

Comment: Working gr8 for the given piece but when  ```s='''........ 
story 1 
......................................................................... 
Bad Day \n
It seems to me that I got up with my left leg today- surprising.. ! 
...... 
story 2 
..................................................................................................  
Names of people born in Brazil \n Brazilians give different names to their children, but there are some that are used more often.'''``` -it is not saving anything, what am i missing?

Comment: Could not click enter button for new lines story1  and story 2  in comments but they are in format as described previously.

Comment: @Arc9 can you Create a new regex101 demo or update the current demo on https://regex101.com/r/9yjyKB/1  with the data that does not match for you and should match?

Comment: here it is : https://regex101.com/r/51Wilu/1

Comment: @Arc9 I see, there are spaces after the dot, and the title can consist of multiple words. Try it like this `^\.{3,}[^\S\n]*\n(?!\.{3})(\S.*)\n\.{3,}[^\S\n]*(?:\n(?!\.{3}).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/cy2ypY/1

Comment: it worked perfectly. The way you made it understand in granular level was wonderful. Just  wanted to ask ,  i tried to know about non capture group (:? but could not understand well. Can you just briefly tell about what is it doing here?

Comment: @Arc9 The non capture group in this case groups the match together so that you can repeat that whole matched part as a whole. So here `(?:\n(?!\.{3}).*)*` you start the group `(?:` and then you match a newline and assert not 3 dots. If that is the case, match the rest of the line and close the group `)*`. The asterix after the group repeat 0 ot more times, that means we are repeatedly matching all lines (because we are starting with a newline in the match) until the assertion (matching 3 dots at the start of the line) fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247332/discussion-between-arc9-and-the-fourth-bird).